# .htaccess doesn't redirect properly from one website to another website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect temporarily from one URL to another URL using .htaccess

> Example :

When browse from URL `www.example.com`, Then I want to redirect `www.another-example.com`. This is working good.

But don't want to redirect anywhere if browse like as `www.example.com/other/path`

But it is always redirecting to `http://www.another-example.com` if i browse like `www.example.com/other/path` other path.

Here is my `.htaccess` code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$   app/      [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/$1    [L]
  Redirect 302 "/" "http://www.another-example.com"
</IfModule>
```

How can I do it by modifying my `.htaccess` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Redirect` directive as it doesn't support regex and exact matching.

Use all `mod_rewrite` rules as in:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.another-example.com [L,R=301]

  RewriteRule    ^$   app/      [L]

  RewriteRule    (.*) app/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

- `^/?$` matches only landing page for current domain.
- Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a different browser when testing this change.